# How mariadb resolves user's hostname?

Tags: mysql, linux

I am using MariaDB on Linux RedHat and running Java App. I am interested in how DB resolves user hostname because I want to use user@localhost instead of user@127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

The name resolution in Linux is done in the [resolver library](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-resolv.library.html). The main functions are  `gethostbyname()` and `gethostbyaddr()`. In the /etc/nsswitch.conf file you can change the search order. You can use the following options:

**dns**

- Use the Domain Name System (DNS) service to resolve the address. This mechanism uses the /etc/resolv.conf file.

**files**

- Search in the /etc/hosts and /etc/network files.

**nis or nisplus**

- Use the Network Information System (NIS) to resolve the host or network address.

In oyur case, is almost the same. The relation between *127.0.0.1* and *localhost* is defined in **/etc/hosts**